# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to perform unit test but getting exception for Iterable

Implemetation code

```
private ClientWrapper clientWrapper;

Iterable<Document> documentIterable=clientWrapper.doOperation(reqList);
```

Test code

```
@Mock
ClientWrapperImpl mocClientWrapper;

Document mockDocuent=Mockito.mock(Document.class);

Iterable<Document>  documentIterable=Mockito.mock(Iterable.class);
Iterator<Document> documentIterator=Mockito.mock(Iterator.class);
Mockito.when(documentIterable.iterator)).thenReturn(documentIterator);
Mockito.when(documentIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
Mockito.when(documentIterator.next()).thenReturn(mockDocuent);

Mockito.when(mocClientWrapper.doOperation(Mockito.anyList())).thenReturn(documentIterable);
```

Exception that i am getting:Full StackTrace

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue
Iterable$MockitoMock$598 cannot be returned by toString()
toString() should return string

If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1.This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2.A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies-- with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
```

This exception showing at line in test class where i am mocking doOperation method.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full stacktrace of the exception.  It's not clear where the exception is being thrown from: I can't see any reason why it would be thrown from any of the lines you have included in your question.

Comment: do i also need to check internal calls as well?

Comment: I don't have the full source code of your `ClientWrapperImpl` class, so without it, the best I can do is to guess that the `doOperation` method of this is `final`.  Because of this, the mock created by Mockito can't override this method. However, I don't see why you are using a mock of the implementation rather than of the interface.  The class you are testing seems to use a `ClientWrapper` rather than a `ClientWrapperImpl`, so I would try changing the type of your `mocClientWrapper` field to `ClientWrapper` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: If I use Client wrapper then it is throwing invalidUseOfMatcherException

Comment: doOperation method is not final

Comment: In interface have Iterable<Document> doOperation(List Doc> var1) method and have implementation of this method in ClientWrapperImpl class and method is public

Comment: "If I use Client wrapper then it is throwing invalidUseOfMatcherException": please edit your question to include this detail, including the full stacktrace of this exception.  This exception looks to me to be the root of your problem, whereas the exception in your question is what you get with your attempt at solving your problem by mocking the implementation rather than the interface.

Comment: Also, I noticed that the first of your lines beginning `Mockito.when` is missing a `(`.  Evidently you haven't compiled and run the code in your question.  It looks to me as if you've anonymised the real code you're running, which I understand you might have to do.  However, if you do this, please ensure that (a) the code you post compiles, and (b) you post enough code to reproduce the problem.  I added the missing `(` and your code does not throw the exception you mention.